# Holoviz Polygon orientation settings

Tags: python, bokeh, scatter-plot, holoviews, holoviz

I am using holoviews+bokeh, and I would like to encircle my scatter plot data with a measure of standard deviation. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the orientation setting right. I am confused by the available descriptions:

> Orientation in the Cartesian coordinate system, the
> counterclockwise angle in radians between the first axis and the
> horizontal
> and

> you can set the orientation (in radians, rotating anticlockwise)

My script and data example:

```
def create_plot(x, y, nstd=5):
    x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
    cov_matrix = np.cov([x, y])
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(cov_matrix)
    order = eigenvalues.argsort()[0]
    angle = np.arctan2(eigenvectors[1, order], eigenvectors[1, order])

    x0 = np.mean(x)
    y0 = np.mean(y)

    x_dir = np.cos(angle) * x - np.sin(angle) * y
    y_dir = np.sin(angle) * x + np.cos(angle) * y

    w = nstd * np.std(x_dir)
    h = nstd * np.std(y_dir)

    return hv.Ellipse(x0, y0, (w, h), orientation=-angle) * hv.Scatter((x, y))

c2x = np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=0.6, size=200)
c2y = np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=0.1, size=200)

combined = create_plot(c2x, c2y)
combined.opts(shared_axes=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, which draws `Ellipse` around the data. You math is just simplified.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts

hv.extension('bokeh')

x = np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=0.6, size=200)
y = np.random.normal(loc=-2, scale=0.1, size=200)

def create_plot(x, y, nstd=5):
    x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)

    x0 = np.mean(x)
    y0 = np.mean(y)

    w = np.std(x)*nstd
    h = np.std(y)*nstd

    return hv.Ellipse(x0, y0, (w, h)) * hv.Scatter((x, y))

combined = create_plot(c2x, c2y)
combined.opts()
```

This gives you a plot which looks like a circle. To make it more visiable that it is a Ellipse your could genereate the plot calling

```
def hook(plot, element):
    plot.handles['x_range'].start = -4
    plot.handles['x_range'].end = 0
    plot.handles['y_range'].start = -2.5
    plot.handles['y_range'].end = -1

combined.opts(hooks=[hook])
```

which set fixed ranges and deactivates the auto focus.

In your example `w` and `h` were nearly the same, that means, you drawed a cercle. The `orientation` didn't have any effect. With the code above you can turn the Ellipse like

```
hv.Ellipse(x0, y0, (w, h), orientation=np.pi/2)
```

to see that it is working, but there is no need to do it anymore.